# Excel - calculating average for which condition don't match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

my data looks like this,

[image: Data]

i want to calculate two things 
1) Promoted week average
2) non promoted week average

For promoted week average the formula i used in 'L' column is

```
{=AVERAGE(IF($A2=$O$2:$O$11,IF($B$1:$M$1=$P$2:$P$11,B2:K2)))}
```

But if use the following for non promoted weeks it wont work

```
{=AVERAGE(IF($A2=$O$2:$O$11,IF($B$1:$M$1<>$P$2:$P$11,B2:K2)))}
```

The reason being not equal operator will produce multiple match (TRUE) in each row of matrix formed.
Please suggest a way around for this.

Comment: so non promoted = total minus promoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calculating promoted weeks with this formula:

`=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$1:K$1,IF(A2=O$2:O$11,P$2:P$11),0)),B2:K2))`

....now for non-promoted weeks you want the opposite so you just change `ISNUMBER` to `ISNA`, i.e.

`=AVERAGE(IF(ISNA(MATCH(B$1:K$1,IF(A2=O$2:O$11,P$2:P$11),0)),B2:K2))`

both confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>